# Adding n-1 comma between Strings

Tags: java, collections, stringbuilder

I hava again run it interesting problem, I need to dynamically build SQL query which contatins the IN condition. So I have list of String and I need to insert them to my `StringBuilder` separated by the coma.

So my first idea was to employ some boolean value to determine if I should insert the coma or not.

```
builder.append("TABLE.METACODES in (");
boolean isFirst = true;
for(String metaCode : cto.getEntityMetaCodes()) {
    if(isFirst) {
        isFirst = false;
        builder.append("'" + metaCode + "'");
    } else {
         builder.append(", '" + metaCode + "'");
    }
 }
 builder.append(")");
```

Can yout think of any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an external library, I would do something like:

```
builder.append("TABLE.METACODES in (");
EntityMetaCodes emc = cto.getEntityMetaCodes();
builder.append("'" + emc.remove(0) + "'"); // assuming it's an ArrayList, remove(0) takes out the
                               // first element and moves everything else to the left
for(String metaCode : emc) {
    builder.append(", '" + metaCode + "'");
}
builder.append(")");
```

Comment: Nice idea, I like this solution most:)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `join` from [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html), this would let the last comma out giving a nice result for what you want.

From documentation:

> Joins the elements of the provided array into a single String
>   containing the provided list of elements.
>
> No delimiter is added before or after the list. A null separator is
>   the same as an empty String (""). Null objects or empty strings within
>   the array are represented by empty strings.

```
 StringUtils.join(null, *)                = null
 StringUtils.join([], *)                  = ""
 StringUtils.join([null], *)              = ""
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "--")  = "a--b--c"
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], null)  = "abc"
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "")    = "abc"
 StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"], ',')   = ",,a"
```

You could use the same approach:

```
builder.append("TABLE.METACODES in ('");
boolean isFirst = true;
StringUtils.join(cto.getEntityMetaCodes(),"','");
builder.append("')");
```

You need to pay attention when collection is empty, because with this approach the result would be a valid sql: `TABLE.METACODES in ('')` and your code would be an invalid one: `TABLE.METACODES in ()`

Comment: Thanks for tip but we are unfortunatelly not using the Apache Commons.

Comment: If you are not using I would advise you to create a Helper class with the method ;) maybe take a look into Apache Commons code... it is already optimized

Comment: you can take a look here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.html line: 3370 (maybe just extract the method as it is to your helper class)

Answer (score 2):

`I need to dynamically build SQL query which contatins the IN condition`.. no, no you really don't. Really, that's horrible on so many levels. There's no reason to manipulate strings for SQL queries these days, that'll only land you in the tech press when you invariably get a SQL injection exploit.

Hibernate can do this easily with collections [see here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29) and I'd hope normal PreparedStatements could do it as well, although it's possible that you'd have to build the in clause manually and then set the variables in a loop afterwards - in which case take Francisco's approach but use placeholders instead.

Comment: I would do that if I could, I have my own reasons for doing this (I need to use Oracles partitioning, so I can't use Criteria API, parameters can vary, so I can't use NamedQueries)

Comment: But hey, in this case you are right, this parameter will be always there, I didn't realized it. Thanks

Comment: @Petr Hibernate (well a port of it..) should support sharding and co, so I'd think that'd work with oracle partitioning too, but never used oracle so don't know. Anyhow you can at least build the preparedstatement using Francisco's approach and let the SQL normalization be done by the JDBC driver. Still a bit messy, but gives you the security.